# Не работают сервисы Firebase

Tags: android, база-данных, firebase, nosql

недавно столкнулся с банальной проблемой: создал аккаунт google для нового приложения и подключил к нему firebase. Затем создал проект firebase, попытался подключить Real Time Data, выбрал тестовый режим и запустил инициализацию (по опыту секунд 15), но мой ноутбук был против и разрядился, в следствии чего инициализация ,видимо, прервалась.

Затем я снова решил зайти во вкладку Databases и радостно увидел бесконечную загрузку и приятный стактрейс ошибок 401 (Bad Auth) и ошибок SSL (Не возможно установить стабильное соединение с сервером) в консоль.

Но я не отчаивался решил перезайти, удалив все связки ключей, к тому же с другого браузера, собственно, ничего не поменялось. Затем решил забить на все это и создать проект на основном аккаунте, но , к еще большему счастью, обнаружил, что на нем тоже не грузятся бдшки! На всех, уже готовых проектах нет бдшек, все тот же стактрейс, те же симптомы, прошу помочь, и , конечно, фотки прилагаю.

[И видео тоже](https://youtu.be/4eCLAAJyQyc)

[image: Это Стактрейс]

[image: Ошибка 401]

[image: Загрузка]

Comment: может дело вообще в роскомнадзоре, если с нового аккаунта всё так же..

Answer (score 0):

UPD:
Через VPN проблема решается
+ Заметил, что проблема в сети, а именно, через мой wifi, wifi на работе и 4g на смартфоне (черный оператор) не работает, но у некоторых друзей, а так же в других офисах (не всегда) работает без vpn. 
Пы.Сы.
Если честно, вообще хз, что происходит.